# Calling mysql stored procedure from mysql command line in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

i want to execute a mysql stored procedure from mysql command prompt in phpmyadmin.stored procedure is written in a file **sample.sql**. contents of sample.sql is:

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure sampleproc()
begin
declare x int;
set x=1;
while x<=1000 do
insert into dictionary (word,mean) values('a','a mean');
set x=x+1;
end while

end //

call sampleproc();
```

How can i run this using command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using PHPMYADMIN

To create a stored procedure, you can use the following :

```
 DELIMITER //
    create procedure sampleproc()
    begin
    declare x int;
    set x=1;
    while x<=1000 do
    insert into dictionary (word,mean) values('a','a mean');
    set x=x+1;
    end while
    end//
```

And make sure you set the "Delimiter" field on the SQL tab to //.

### Using Command Line

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name < sample.sql
```

Comment: mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name < sample.sql

execute this command from windows/linux shell not from mysql command line

Comment: i have run it but error occurs like C:\>mysql --user=root --password=" " test < d:/sample.sql
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: make sure mysql command is executable one. set the mysql path in environment variables or use abosulte path to mysql like c:\>F:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin\mysql --user=root --password=" " test < d:/sample.sql

Comment: i didn't make it to work..i have set the path correct to /bin..and add the command..it shos that u have an error in sql syntax

Comment: try to remove this line "call sampleproc();" from sql file

Comment: Thanks Venu Gopal now its working like a charm...its bcoz of the wrong path.. pls update ur answer

Comment: Thanks...It might helpful to others